# When does Urbanization occur in Age of Steam

Tags: age-of-steam

I am second in turn order, I select Urbanization.  Do I place the city at the start of my build track phase or before the first person who builds track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You place the new city as your first action during your Build Track phase.

On page 2 of the rules

> **Urbanization action:**
>
> Implemented during the Build Track phase.  This action allows this player to place one of the New City tiles on a Town **before** they build their track.

This is from the Warfrog edition (2002).  It seems the [rules haven't changed](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5747256#5747256) much at all despite the plethora of editions.

Comment: Thanks Pat.  My edition of the rules is worded slightly differently which made it less clear.  Good link.